# Бесконечный цикл javascript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

подскажите пожалуйста почему данный цикл выполняется бесконечно?
Если перед $.get поставить console.log("123") это выводиться бесконечно и в итоге зависает браузер, а то и вообще windows. Но тем не менее $.get не выполняется вообще.

```
addresa = pictures.split(":")
count = addresa.length;
nowfile = 0;
openw = 4

while(nowfile < count) {
 $.get("http://192.168.1.108/photos/" + addresa[nowfile], function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  str = "data:image/jpg;base64," + data
  docInfo['content'][openw] = { image: str };
  console.log("ban")
  openw = openw + 1;
  nowfile = nowfile + 1;
  ban = ban + 1;
  pdfMake.createPdf(docInfo).download(addres + '.pdf');
 });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас получилось синхронное выполнение бесконечного цикла, который регистрирует асинхронные XHR запросы и не освобождает поток, тем самым не давая шанс им выполнится.

Измените условие у цикла на `while (nowfile++ < count) { ...` - зарегистрирует требуемое кол-во XHR запросов и завершится, после этого начнут отрабывать запросы.

Почитать про асинхронность в javascript можно, например, [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/wrike/blog/302896/).

Comment: И тут не помешало бы добавить, что синхронный запрос не решил бы проблему, т.к. callback-фунцкия передается аргументом в метод `$.get()` и, соответственно не выполняется непосредственно в цикле. Это означает, что инкремент `nowfile` происходит вне области видимости.

Comment: @Deonis, ты что-то не то говоришь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, может я объясняюсь не очень правильно, т.к. я в большей степени не теоретик, а практик. В таком случае, возможно, что [код это сделает за меня](https://jsfiddle.net/er486m7v/). )) Запрос синхронный и чтобы не мучит браузер - цикл ограничен.

Comment: @Deonis, потому что `GET https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json/ 404`. Успешный коллбек на 404 не выполняется вообще.